# Does a battery capacity depend on the load?

Tags: batteries

[image]

The source is

https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf2/AAA4000/AAA4000C321.pdf

I have seen a specification of the following

**CR2032**: Lithium Batteries

**Product**: Lithium Batteries

**Series/Type**: Coin type lithium batteries (CR series)

**Parts no**: CR2032

**Manufacturer**: Panasonic

It shows that the capacity of the battery is a function of a load resistance. To me, a battery capacity can be affected by temperature, pressure, humidity and other factors, but I cannot see why the resistance can affect its capacity.

I am aware that the capacity will be decreased if it is discharged, but the data sheet does not state the time so I assume
**\$t = 0\$** s

If \$Q = 225\$ mAh

\$i = 1\$ mA

time will be \$t = 225\$ h.

If \$Q = 225\$ mAh

\$i = 5\$ mA

time will be \$t = 45\$ h.

So time will change not the charge. This is how I see it

**

### The battery capacity is a design in characteristic.

**

Comment: You're not including losses to the battery that go up with increasing current draw. Draw more current, you create more heat. That heat generated amounts to effective capacity lost to the battery and not utilized by the load.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Batteries have an internal resistance. The power lost to this internal resistance is proportional to the current squared. Integrate this power across time, and that's where the "lost" capacity goes - internal heating of the battery. Notice these curves are quadratic in nature. The losses go up a lot with incremental current draw increases due to this i^2 effect. Below is a lump component model of the battery with values approximated from the characteristic curves @ 20deg C.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKJxXE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The power, and therefore the capacity, dissipated  by R1 goes up quadratically with current consumed at the load. This capacity is lost internal to the battery. The 2V cut-off limit is when the battery is considered dead and current drawn after that is no longer guaranteed because the battery can no longer maintain the voltage. This is only a simple model and ignores higher order effects like leakage or any other long-term chemical degradation effects, but should be good enough to understand why the effective battery capacity decreases with a higher load.

Comment: @Colin I don't think you understand this well enough. What I've stated is absolutely relevant to the question. What do you think is drawing the current from the battery? I've edited my post for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly capacity is affected by the load. At one extreme (almost zero load) there is no capacity since it's all eaten up by self-discharge.

At the other extreme (very heavy load) there is also no capacity since the battery cannot deliver 2.0V into the load due to the internal resistance.

The internal electrochemical processes inside the battery have losses that generally increase as the load current increases, on top of the internal resistance. Things like electrode polarization, for example.

Comment: Still not clear

Comment: A fresh CR2032 has a short-circuit current of maybe 300mA so if you connect a load of less than about 20Ω there will be less than 2V across the load an you've already reached the end of life load voltage marker. The datasheet numbers are correct for Panasonic batteries (possibly optimistic for off-brand types) and you should use them. If you want to get into the gritty details of battery design, that's probably OT here.

Comment: if Q = 225 mAh and i = 1 mA, so t = 225 hours.
if Q = 225 mAh and i = 5 mA, so t = 45 hours.

So time will change not the charge. This is how I see it

Comment: It's a useful approximation (constant mAh capacity) over a wide range of currents, certainly from 100uA down to a uA (maybe a 100:1 range), but over a wider range it's not an accurate approximation. And 5mA is way outside the range where it is accurate. The CR2032 is most useful for relatively low current-draw situations, but all batteries will have a similar characteristic.

Comment: Regarding very heavy load, I think there is a full capacity because the current will be 2nA or less so the effective capacity is full

Answer (score 1):

Well, to little surprise, the battery datasheet is right, and your assumption that load plays no role in capacity is wrong.

In essence, the process by which a battery supplies current depends on the migration of Ions through some medium.  At the same time, deposition on the electrodes limits the availability of conductive surface.

By discharging a battery fast, you can increase the internal resistance permanently, and make fewer ions available for transport.